# How should a sparkline show small changes to large data values?

Tags: data-visualization

I've got a UI that uses sparklines to show trends. But in some situations, I've got a series of data points with values that start at some large number and increase slowly, such as:

13000,13001,13002,13003

As sparklines, they render like this:

[image]

This is accurate, in the sense that is shows the number increasing linearly, but kind of misleading, since the actual change is negligible compared to the starting value.

What is a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: If you have all positive values, changes on the log scale are appropriate. see *Whatever Has Happened to the Semilogarithmic Chart?* ([Schmid, 1986](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00031305.1986.10475401)) for some discussion.